# What are the effects of mass extinction?

Tags: science-based, biology, magic, fauna

In an “Ancient Greek” technological world a magical plague causes the extinction of all animals larger than a chicken, or say 5lbs/2kg. Some Humans and small animals (cats and dogs) survive this by virtue of being deep underground.

1000 years passes.

- Would many species of flora end up dying off?
- Would the dominant species end up being hares, boars and hawks?
- How would the lack of draft animals effect society?
- How would the lack of animals effect warfare?
- How much larger can existing animals be bred over hundreds of years?
- What sort of unknowns have I not considered?

Comment: Boars and hawks are usually bigger than that...

Comment: I was thinking baby pygmies would survive.https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pygmy_hog Also, hawks are about 1kg so they survive.

Comment: Way to broad, each question by themselves are pushing too broad.

Comment: SE's model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer.  I count 7.  Additionally, the "too broad" rules are that a question that would require a book to answer all of the considered conditions is also too broad.  Questions #1, #2, #4, #5, and #7, even if asked individually, are too broad.  Questions #3 and #6 are primarily opinion-based unless criteria is provided to explain how you will judge a best answer.  Please consider asking questions in our [question sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168) to perfect them before posting them on the main site.